# Are Yazidis of Iraq related to Hinduism?

Tags: other-religions

I saw a video on youtube and read about [Yazidis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yazidis):

> The Yazidis are monotheists,believing in God as creator of the world,
>   which he has placed under the care of seven holy beings or angels, the
>   chief of whom is Melek Taus, the Peacock Angel. The Peacock Angel, as
>   world-ruler, causes both good and bad to befall individuals, and this
>   ambivalent character is reflected in myths of his own temporary fall
>   from God's favor, before his remorseful tears extinguished the fires
>   of his hellish prison and he was reconciled with God.

- The purity of Earth, Air, Fire and Water is protected by a number of taboos, e.g. against spitting on earth, water or fire.
- Their children are baptised at birth and **circumcision is not required**, but is practised by some due to regional customs.
- Their temples have domes like we have in Hinduism.

[image]

**My question:** Is this peacock angel [Kartikeya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya)? Are they related to Hinduism in some way, probably migrated there? How come a peacock reached a deserted region?

Comment: @Rajas. which evil forces exactly? But they seem more peace loving then some of their counterparts in that region.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar but they worship peacock and heard they don't marry same gotra too...unlike muslims

Comment: Yes , But only possible connection we can find is " Early writers attempted to describe Yazidi origins, broadly speaking, in terms of Pagan" religions. And also although Kartikeya is widely worshiped in south India . But he is not among the central deities  of hinduism. But I just now found out  that the shaivas established the Shaivism far upto Egypt , Brazil etc.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar very interesting. Can you share some link to read about Shaivas in those places? I read about BogaNathar traveling to Chile, in South America, and there some native people call him Bocha: [Bocha, who gave laws to Muycas, was a white, bearded man, wearing long robes, who regulated the calendar, established festivals, and vanished in time like others](http://palani.org/bhogar-biography.htm)

Comment: they are a christian denomination.